# Resolution problem Ubuntu 15.10 after 4.2.0-18 linux update

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, screen, display-resolution

I have an NVIDIA GeForce GT540M video card and since I updated from Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10 I've had a LOT of problems with my screen. No nvidia privative driver will work (all of them give me a black screen), I've already tried all the solutions out there and none of them have worked for my laptop. I decided to use Xorg-server, and that worked with some minor problems but did the trick until last linux update from 4.2.0-16 to 4.2.0-18, then my screen resolution broke. I only have one option 640 x 480 and can't change anything.

I have already tried:
- All default privative drivers
- Clean installation
- Removing /etc/X11/xorg.conf file
- Installing extra nvidia drivers from their site

And nothing works.

Lucky for me, I can still use Linux 4.2.0-16 but I wish to move to 4.2.0-18.

Thank you for any help/tip provided.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is right.
For example you know your monitor can display fullHD picture:

```
user@pc:~$ xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }'
DVI-1
user@pc:~$ cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
user@pc:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
user@pc:~$ sudo xrandr --addmode DVI-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

Comment: Well, as I said before, I get this error:      Failed to get size of gamma for output default default  Which means, I will not be able to user xrandr sadly

Comment: try without sudo

Answer (score 0):

finally I got the problem solved, I had to go to this site:

ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/

and looked for latest driver, in my case:

ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/358.16/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-358.16.run

Downloaded it and install the driver following:

ftp:/...XFree86/Linux-x86_64/358.16/README/README.txt

And it worked.

Thank you everyone for your replies.

Best regards